# Unparsable Date format?

Tags: java, gwt, date-format, gxt

```
public  void lvd() throws Exception {   
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
    Date currentTime = DateUtil.getTimestamp(new Date(), "00:00");
    String last=  formatter.format(currentTime);
    UtilLog.writeLVD(last);  //date.txt
}
```

This is code for reading the current date and write in to date.txt file.

```
String last=utilLog.readLVD();
SimpleDateFormat form = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
lastVerificationTime = form.parse(last);
```

Here lastVDate is reading from file as a string and i have converted to date format.
some times working fine. but some times it occurs following exception. can u help me for this problem. weather problem is reading a file or parsing the date from string ?

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "l??F[?14"
    at java.text.DateFormat.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:543)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:136)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1220)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:513)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:448)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.jetty.JettyLauncher$WebAppContextWithReload.doStart(JettyLauncher.java:468)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:39)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.RequestLogHandler.doStart(RequestLogHandler.java:115)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:39)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:222)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:39)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.jetty.JettyLauncher.start(JettyLauncher.java:672)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.doStartUpServer(DevMode.java:509)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.startUp(DevModeBase.java:1093)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.run(DevModeBase.java:836)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.main(DevMode.java:311)




     public static void writeLVD(String LastDate) throws Exception {


    try {
        File file = new File(System.getProperty("APPLICATION_HOME") + "/temp.file");
        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.createNewFile();
        }

        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        bw.write(LastDate);
        bw.close();


    } catch (IOException e) {
        logger.error(ListValueUtil.class.getName() + "",e );
    }
}

public  String readLVD() {
    File file = new File(System.getProperty("APPLICATION_HOME") + "/temp.file");
    FileInputStream fis = null;
    BufferedInputStream bis = null;
    DataInputStream dis = null;
    String key = null;
    try {
        fis = new FileInputStream(file);
        bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
        dis = new DataInputStream(bis);
        while (dis.available() > 0) {
            key = (String) dis.readLine();

        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        logger.error(ListValueUtil.class.getName() + "",e );
e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            fis.close();
            bis.close();
            dis.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            logger.error(ListValueUtil.class.getName() + "",ex );
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return key;
}
```

Comment: Well look at the error - the value it's parsing is simply not a date. It looks like the problem is in `readLVD` (or `writeLVD`), not the parsing. Unfortunately you haven't provided that code, so we can't help you find the problem in it.

Comment: Does `"l??F[?14"` look like a parseable date?

Comment: update the question with readLVD() and writeLVD() methods implementations ...

Comment: Hey frnds, i updated read and write methods

Answer (score 0):

Your `writeLVD(String LastDate)` is not writing its argument.  It is writing `imlogLicenseKey`.

So, it looks like you are trying to parse a licence key as a date ... and that why you get the exception.

---

There are all sorts of other attrocities in your code including:

- identifier style violations (such as `LastDate`),
- declaring a method as throwing `Exception`, and
- potential resource leaks and potential NPEs due to sloppy handling of your streams.

Read about Java 7 "try with resource".

Read (carefully!) the javadocs for the `close()` methods on the stream classes that you are using.